# How to fetch axios post request response as a table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I've made a post request using `Axios` and I can see the response stored in the data object in my Devtools console.

I tried iterating over it using `map` function. But the array is empty for some reason.

`Axios` POST request :-

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8080/accountStatus', {
      username : "username",
      accountStatus : "status"
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

The items array has been initialized in my constructor. 
Render method :-

```
var {items, username, accountStatus} = this.state;
<div className="App">
          <table>
          <thead>
               <td>
                {items.map(item =>
                  <tbody>
                    {item.username}
                  </tbody>
                )}
              </td>  
          </thead>
          </table>
</div>
```

Error is that items array is undefined. 
The items array is empty and hence I'm not able to iterate over the array using map(). The endpoint works fine and I've tested it. Please help me resolve this.

Comment: can you post a sample data set that you need to show (which is in your state)

Comment: You are using `function` keyword with arrow `=>` . Are you sure we are allowed to so in Javascript? i.e`function(json) => {`

Comment: @iRohitBhatia I've removed that now. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this async code also like this

```
async componentDidMount(){
   const items = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/accountStatus',{username : "username",
  accountStatus : "status"}
  this.setState({isLoaded:true,items});
}
```

Comment: I'm making the axios post request inside my ```componentDidMount()``` function. So should that be an async method?

Answer (score 0):

This should probably work.

as panther mentioned, One way of doing it would be to use async so this is a valid code

```
async componentDidMount(){
   const items = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/accountStatus',{username : "username",
  accountStatus : "status"}
  this.setState({isLoaded:true,items});
}
```

In Nane code/comment you mentioned that

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

For that you do either of these two things

```
const that = this
axios.post('http://localhost:8080/accountStatus', {
      username : "username",
      accountStatus : "status"
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        that.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        items: response,
      })
    })
```

or use arrow function instead

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8080/accountStatus', {
      username : "username",
      accountStatus : "status"
    })
    .then((response) => {
        that.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        items: response,
      })
    })
```

or `bind this` keyword

Also, as mentioned in the comment, I am not sure if you can use function with arrow, saying that review the following line in your code (which is anyway unnecessary)

```
function(json) => {
```

Comment: I tried what you said. I'm not able to map over items array yet. It's still undefined. I've removed the ```function(json)``` also . Still getting the same ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined```